# Pyplot color maps showing different results

Tags: python, matplotlib, scikit-image

Playing a bit with some scikit-image code samples and pyplot I've found different results on my images depending on how I'm applying my color maps, and I don't know why.

When I apply a color map as a plugin when showing an image, everything goes OK, when I do it directly to the image, it goes totally black. I'm confused because I want to apply that color maps to images I want to save (instead of show) and I don't know how to do it properly.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from skimage import data
from skimage.color import rgb2hed


ihc_rgb = data.immunohistochemistry()
ihc_hed = rgb2hed(ihc_rgb)

fig, axes = plt.subplots(2, 2, figsize=(7, 6))
ax0, ax1, ax2, ax3 = axes.ravel()

ax0.imshow(ihc_hed[:, :, 0], cmap=plt.cm.gray)
ax0.set_title("plugin")

ax1.imshow(plt.cm.gray(ihc_hed[:, :, 0]))
ax1.set_title("direct")
```

[this goes on a bit]

[image]

Comment: Good! Both Hitzg and Stefan had very nice answers, but finally Stefan got me on track. Thank you both for helping this newbie.

Comment: For future questions: don't involve a library (here matplotlib) only for the purpose of asking the question. Your problem was actually about scaling skimages

Comment: Thanks @hitzg , at first I didn't know my problem was about scaling. Now I know. My fault.

Comment: Sorry that came across a bit too aggressive... no harm intended

Comment: No offense taken! ;)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The values inside `ihc_hed[:, :, 0]` lie between -1.37 and -0.99.  The default behavior of `imshow` is to display the whole range of values.  `plt.cm.gray`, on the other hand, operates on images with values between 0 and 1.

The automatic rescaling is saving you in the first case, but not the second.  I recommend always using `imshow` with a fixed range: `imshow(image, vmin=0, vmax=1, cmap='gray')`

Comment: How could I rescale on the second case? I want to apply the map to an image I?m saving instead of showing it... Thanks!

Comment: You can import ``rescale_intensity`` from ``skimage.exposure``, then: ``rescaled_image = exposure.rescale_intensity(image, out_range=(0, 1))``

Answer (score 1):

From the your comment on the [Stefan van der Walt](https://stackoverflow.com/users/214686/stefan-van-der-walt)'s [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27262405/4177384) I conclude that you dont want to save matplotlib figures, but images directly.
As Stefan pointed out, you need to scale the values before you can use the colormap. Matplotlib provides the class `Normalize` for that:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.colors
from skimage import data
from skimage.color import rgb2hed

ihc_rgb = data.immunohistochemistry()
ihc_hed = rgb2hed(ihc_rgb)

fig, axes = plt.subplots(1, 3, figsize=(8, 3))
ax0, ax1, ax2 = axes.ravel()

ax0.imshow(ihc_hed[:, :, 0], cmap=plt.cm.gray)
ax0.set_title("plugin")

ax1.imshow(plt.cm.gray(ihc_hed[:, :, 0]))
ax1.set_title("direct")

norm = matplotlib.colors.Normalize()
gray_image = plt.cm.gray(norm(ihc_hed[:,:,0])) 

ax2.imshow(gray_image)
ax2.set_title("direct with norm")

for a in axes:
    a.xaxis.set_visible(False)
    a.yaxis.set_visible(False)

plt.gcf().tight_layout()
plt.show()
```

[image]

Comment: Funny thing is, when I apply a normalization and the image doesn't contain values lower than 0 and higher than 1, it becomes blank (white). I'm checking normalization options to find why...

Comment: What do you mean by *it becomes blank*? After saving to disk? I can not reproduce the problem

Comment: before saving, check this and sorry about my lousy code:
[Code in pastebin](http://pastebin.com/aTUdgntV) (it needs a 'resources' folder, sorry)

Comment: Create a new instance of `Normalize` for each image you want to process. `Normalize` internally sets is `vmin` and `vmax` upon the first call to it (if you dont specify them when creating the instance).

Comment: Oh damn. Thank you a lot. If I could accept both answers... :'(